# Style a embedded video for mobile version

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style a video, because on the mobile version the video does not fit the screen. I have the following HTML code:

```
      <li>
        <a class="uk-accordion-title" href="#">How much is the fish?</a>
        <div class="uk-accordion-content">
       <p><div class="iframe-container">
          <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cbB3iGRHtqA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div></p>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

So in order to style the video for the mobile version I did the following:

```
.iframe-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
  height: 0;
}
.iframe-container iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

However when I make these changes in my CSS document, it does not make any chances. I am not too sure what I do wrong here. Is it the fact that I do not select the right element? Also I have a picture of the full code which is to large to post: [Full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvnnU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I left your HTML and CSS as it is but I changed your width in your css

```css
.iframe-container{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
  max-height: 0;
}
.iframe-container iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
    max-width:100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<li>
        <a class="uk-accordion-title" href="#">How much is the fish?</a>
        <div class="uk-accordion-content">
       <p><div class="iframe-container">
          <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cbB3iGRHtqA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div></p>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```